# How do I change background color of individual card?

Tags: html, css

I have defined cards in my css. Assigning a background color in css would make every cards of same color. How do I make those two cards of different background color? Is there any inline solution for it?

```css
/* Float four columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.card {
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
  </div><div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Card 1</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Card 2</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: How is your HTML being generated? Why can't you just add a class to those cards to change the background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a million ways to do it.  Here's one (I added the "othercard" class to one of them).

```css
/* Float four columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.card {
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

.othercard {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
  </div><div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Card 1</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="card othercard">
      <h3>Card 2</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
```